# Merging two data set in R (Based on ID and Range Date)

Tags: r

I have two large data sets.

- The first data set includes ID, Starting time and Ending time.
- The second data set includes ID, Starting time and Ending time.

I want to merge these two data sets based on ID and Starting time by considering the fact that each date from the first data set can merge to any date with its range of 5 days more or less. It means if we have 23/4/2012 in the first data set, It can merge to any staring date between 18/4/2012 to 28/4/2012.

*Input data:*

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10)
StartTime<-c(24/5/1980,2/6/1932,24/6/1945,25/9/1954,12/11/1970,14/3/1984,15/5/1999,20/5/1990,25/9/1981,28/2/1980,29/1/1984,24/4/1987,30/6/1988)
Endtime<-c(24/6/1980,2/8/1932,24/9/1945,25/10/1954,14/11/1970,14/12/1984,15/10/1999,26/5/1990,29/9/1981,28/3/1980,29/1/1984,24/6/1987,30/7/1988)
df1<-data.frame(x,StartTime,Endtime)

x<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7)
StartTime<-c(29/5/1980,20/5/1980,23/5/1945,5/6/1932,7/6/1932,27/6/1945,20/6/1945,20/5/1990,25/9/1981,28/2/1980,29/3/1984,24/5/1987,30/7/1988)
Endtime1<-c(24/6/1980,2/8/1990,24/9/1945,25/10/1954,14/11/1970,14/12/1984,15/10/1999,26/5/1990,29/9/1981,28/3/1980,29/1/1984,24/6/1987,30/7/1988)
df2<-data.frame(x,StartTime,Endtime2)
```

Comment: You can try `foverlaps` from `library(data.table)`

Comment: could you please explain more, thanks.

Comment: If you know SQL, you could also use sqldf for this in a quite straightforward way. If your data sets are large, a 'rolling join' solution using data.table as @akrun suggests will be far more performant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I am not familiar with SQL!

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want the result to be. You want to merge the two data frames but you use different column names. Could you post the expected result from the join in your example code?

Comment: I renamed the variables, Now we have the same columns in two data sets.

Comment: The best way to clarify would probably be to provide the desired output, some `df_out` that corresponds to the input you've given.

Comment: I meant you used different names for _all_ columns which makes it unclear which one would be the 'id variable' for the join. It is just as unclear, still. Please write down an example of what you consider to be the desired output from this join operation.

Comment: The output would be like:                                                                                      ID StartTime Endtime Endtime1        1  24/5/1980  24/6/1980 24/6/1980  since 29/5/1980 is 5 days more than 24/5/1980, we can merge ID 1 and these two starting time together. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3):

Convert your date strings to Dates using as.POSIXct() https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html

```
library(sqldf)
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT df1.*, df2.* FROM df1 INNER JOIN df2 ON julianday(df1.StartDate) - julianday(df2.StartDate) BETWEEN -5 AND 5 AND df1.ID = df2.ID")
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Great solution. Thanks so much for your help. Just I was wondering if you could also write the code for merging based on ID and date too?

Comment: @shadi edited the answer to include the code for joining based on ID and date difference.